# I found a new paradigm: system

Tags: c++

I am currently learning how to process command line arguments. I have a program that needs to call another program, both written in C++. I have a Windows computer. This is the program

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

void main()
{   
    char buffer[200];
    char arg1[6]="Hello";
    std::stringstream buffer;
    sprintf(buffer, "C:\system.exe %i %i", arg1);
    system(buffer);     

    system("pause");
}
```

I need to to call the following program:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void main(int argc, char*argv[])
{       
    string baci;        
    for(int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
        baci += argv[i];

    if (baci=="Hello")
        cout << "Francesco, ti mando 4 baci !!!" << endl;   

    system("pause");
}
```

It's not creating the command line correctly and I can't figure out why. Can anyone help and also explain any variation needed to use a double argument for the system executable ? Books and the net are not very detailed about this procedure. What I found decent was only this but I am unable to use it for my purposes.
[C++: How to use command line arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12285138/c-how-to-use-command-line-arguments)

Comment: Can you edit your question so it's more clear what specific question you are asking?

Comment: I would be very intrested in how you came up with this question title...

Comment: I am not sure as to what you want.  However if you want a second argument it seems you would want something like ```sprintf(buffer,"C:\system.exe %i %i %i",arg1,arg1,arg2)```.

Comment: How is this a new `system` paradigm?

Comment: @PlasmaHH - I am still laughing. Actually the site did not post my question with a title like "sytem()","a problem with system()", "how to pass parameters to system()", etc. so I had an inspiration and I wrote this title which came through. My question is actually HOW TO SEND PARAMETERS USING THE SYSTEM() FUNCTION. Well, I am italian and I learned from italian politicians :-)))) ( they say whatever they think can sound "cool" to catch even just a vote more ) so this title became .... a new paradigm ! LOL

Comment: @FrancescoPalazzetti: while you laugh we wasted some time try to understand what between the tile and the text was wrong.  We are all volunteer and not payed to waste our time, so please be "polite" and let "politics" outside of here. No one cares who you are or where are from and what opinion you have, here. Using and incongruent title serves only to keep right answers away, since it is the first thing someone see, and "tunes" on.

Comment: I understand your point and you have my apologies but, as I explained, I posted that title only after a long series of attempts.

Comment: Sorry but your first example does not compile. "warning C4129: 's' : unrecognized character escape sequence" ;)

Answer (score 0):

Aside from your code not compiling there are a couple of glaring problems. First there is no such thing as `void main()` in C++. It **must** return an `int`. The second problem is you are redeclaring `buffer` as a `std::stringstream`. The third issue  with this is the fact that you are then passing it by value to as the first argument to `sprintf` which will not work since it's neither a `char*` or being passed by pointer. The forth problem is you are trying to expand the argument as an integer value (`%i`) instead of a C style string (`%s`). You are also have two format specifiers for arguments but only pass one. The result of this is undefined and the second `%i` can expand to any value.

Your code should probably look something like this...

```
int main()
{   
    char buffer[200];
    char arg1[6]="Hello";
    sprintf(buffer, "C:\\system.exe %s", arg1);
    system(buffer);     

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

To pass a `double` as an argument just change the [print specifier](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) in the format string.

```
    double arg1 = 1.0f;
    sprintf(buffer, "C:\\system.exe %lf", arg1);
```

To pass more than one argument you need to include an additional format specifier and pass the argument to `sprintf`

```
    sprintf(buffer, "C:\\system.exe %s %s %i", arg1, arg2string, arg3int);
```

Your second program also has a problem and I don't think it's going to execute the way you expect. As Thomas pointed out in his comment you are concatenating the arguments together and then doing a comparison. If you execute it as `system.exe hello there` then `baci` will be `hello there` which seems incorrect. Since you only want to see if `Hello` has been sent you should check it in your loop instead of concatenating the string.

```
void main(int argc, char*argv[])
{       
    for(int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
        if (0 == strcmp(argv[i], "Hello"))
            cout << "Francesco, ti mando 4 baci !!!" << endl;   

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Another issue is: `baci += argv[i];` which will concatenate all the arguments without spaces between them.  I don't think this is what the OP wants.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Nope not what he wants at all. I noticed it when I edited his question. Adding a note for it now.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious. Sorry but your first example does not compile. "warning C4129: 's' : unrecognized character escape sequence"

Comment: @CaptainObvlious. Perfect !  Thank you a lot ! Yep, I did not see the \  ... with all the C++ complexity who thinks about it ? Sorry for the disturb.